# SWT make impossible to close the org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Dialog window

Tags: swt

Tell me, how to make it impossible to close the window which extends "org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Dialog" by Esc key?

my code is [here](http://pastebin.com/teRWXdwa):

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a listener to `shlTimeDiagramsWindow` on `SWT.Traverse`. If the event is escape key, we set the event for that to false. You can add the below snippet code to method `open(int coordX, int coordY)`.

```
shlTimeDiagramsWindow.addListener(SWT.Traverse, new Listener() {

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        if (event.character == SWT.ESC)
        {
            System.out.println("escape key");
            event.doit = false;
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works fine! I`ve forget about event.doit option